# HTML make fonts scale the same way as the page

Tags: html, css

I want to create an A4 style page in HTML. However I want it to look the same whenever I zoom
in and out. For example look at the following screenshots:

[image: Normal Zoom][image: Zoom Out]

When I zoom out, the paragraph looks longer inside the page. What I want is a Word Style
zoom in and out.

Here is the way this page is coded:

```
<div class="document">
<div    class="page">
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>

        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: grey;
}


.page{
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:50px;
    width:210mm;
    height:297mm;
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:0px;
}

.content{
    background-color:   orange;
    margin:10%;
}
```

Comment: +1 for visual description and good question format.

Comment: Did you try setting the exact font size in pixels for your content?

Comment: Here is a question with scaling relative to container options http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container

Comment: Your code works fine on my Chrome 37 on Windows. Only the last zoom out to 25% distorts the text to fill up more of the page. I think it's just related to how Chrome handles small font sizes. This renders fine on IE 11 in all zoom levels.

Comment: @Floremin Looking at this in firefox, it does a similar thing. Still the layout of the page would change.

Comment: @Floremin Post as an answer if you'd like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webkit browsers (like Chrome or Opera) try to resize the text on low zoom (like 25%) to make it readable. If you look at the computed css you will notice that the font size is changing, even if you define it in your css. You would need a plugin, that disables this resizing.

**100% zoom in chrome**

[image: 100% zoom chrome]

**25% zoom in chrome**

[image: 25% zoom chrome]

**Internet Explorer dont resizes the font-size on low zoom**

[image: ie]